# Android Fastboot devices not returning device

Tags: android, installation, fastboot

At the moment I would like to reinstall Android on my device(custom hardware device). I got the image files after building. But when I enter `fastboot devices` nothing returns.

`adb devices` is working. It return my device. `fastboot flashall -w` is also not working. I returns `<waiting for devices>` and stays like that until I exit.

So the 70-android.rules.d file is right. I have also set ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT. `But someone knows why fastboot does not see my device, but adb does?`

Restarting udev or adb does not work. Some people recommend that on the internet.

OS: Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: It might be useful to mention your which OS your computer runs as well as some information about the hardware rather than "custom". It also might be more useful to ask this on http://forum.xda-developers.com/ as XDA deals more with custom roms and things.

Comment: Did you boot into bootloader and usb is connected?
do you have usb drivers for your device?

Comment: Have you found an answer? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 93):

**For Windows:**

- Open device manager
- Find Unknown "Android" device (likely listed under Other devices with an exclamation mark)
- Update driver
- Browse my computer for driver software
- Let me pick from a list of devices, select List All Devices
- Under "Android device" or "Google Inc", you will find "Android Bootloader Interface"
- Choose "Android Bootloader Interface"
- Click "yes" when it says that driver might not be compatible

Comment: Sweet, that worked for me. Unfortunately OP was not running Windows so this probably won't get any upvotes, but this definitely worked for me on Windows.

Comment: Works for me, too. Excellent!!

Comment: Android Bootloader Interface driver for the Fastboot and ADB interface driver for the ADB operations

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: What if it's already listed as "SAMSUNG Mobile USB CDC Composite Device"?

Comment: This saved me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In case you don't find the drivers while listing all devices, try to use the one from google (https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb)

Comment: In my case, I had to install the driver as an “optional update” from the Windows Settings app.

Comment: Given Win10+Android Studio ElectricEel installation of USB drivers from SDK Tools, point the path after clicking "browse my computer" to where you installed the SDK Tools. Top level of SDK tools folder worked fine for me. To verify path, go to File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK and look at the path in the right pane. Worked for me, anyway. Didn't get list of devices option, so if you get stuck on that step and installed the drivers with AS, this is the steps I used.

Answer (score 61):

Are you rebooting the device into the bootloader and entering fastboot USB on the bootloader menu?

Try

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

then look for on screen instructions to enter fastboot mode.

Comment: yep, once i issue "adb reboot bootloader", I get into the fastboot screen - and then "fastboot devices" starts working. That's wierd and i don't know why, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: When the phone is in fastboot mode it announces itself as a different device. That results in an additional device driver on the computer side that has to be installed.

Comment: Great pointer. ``adb reboot-bootloader`` was what worked for me though.

Comment: Apparently Fastbook does not talk to a device that is currently in recovery (that was my problem at least). Running this completely solved my problem (updating CWM Recovery to a newer version)

Comment: Thanks it worked..After  adb reboot-bootloader, i went to device manager and installed usb driver manually..

Comment: @Fydo are you sure about that hiphen, you may be wrong on that. Everybody else does adb reboot bootloader. with no hiphen

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR** - In addition to the previous responses. There might be a problem with the version of the `fastboot` command. Try to download the newest one via **Android SDK Manager** instead of default one available in the OS repository.

There is one more thing you can do to fix this issue. I had the similar problem when trying to flash Nexus Player. All the adb commands we working fine while in **normal** boot mode. However, after switching to **fastboot** mode I wasn't able to execute fastboot commands. My device was not visible in the output of the `fastboot devices` command. I've set the right rules in */etc/udev/rules.d/11-android.rules* file. The `lsusb` command showed that the device has been pluged in.

The soultion was quite simple. I've downloaded the the `fastboot` via Android Studio's SDK Manager instead of using the default one available in Ubuntu packages.

All you need is [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html). Download the **Android SDK Platform Tools** and replace the default */usr/bin/fastboot* with the new one.

Comment: after a long research and many frustrating failures, this was the solution for me too.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but I was running Ubuntu 12.04 through a VM.  I am using a Nexus 10.  I had added the usb device as a filter for the VM (using virtual box in the virtual machine's settings).

The device I had added was "samsung Nexus 10".

The problem is that once the device is in fastboot mode, it shows up as a different device:  "Google, Inc Android 1.0."  So doing "lsusb" in the VM showed no device connected, and obviously "fastboot devices" returned nothing until I added the "second" device as a filter for the VM as well.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

You must run fastboot as root. Try `sudo fastboot`

Comment: It's same, still not showing anything. Anything I need to cross check, Any file permission !!

Comment: This worked for me in WSL (using usbipd).

Answer (score -2):

If you got nothing when inputted `fastboot devices`, it meaned you devices fail to enter fastboot model. Make sure that you enter fastboot model via press these three button simultaneously, power key, volume key(both '+' and '-').
Then you can see you devices via `fastboot devices` and continue to flash your devices.

note:I entered fastboot model only pressed 'power key' and '-' key before, and present the same problem.